# Unable to create reset button for ASP MVC cshtml

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on a project that uses ASP MVC and I have issue making my reset button work.

```
<button type="reset" id="accReset"> </button>
```

this only clears the textfield but it does not clear or reset the dropdownlist that i am having.

This is an example of my implementation for the dropdownlist in cshtml file

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClientCode, Model.ClientCodeList, new { @class = "form-control show-tick bootstrap-select-wrap-text" })
```

To receive the click action I added the following in the js file

```
function onClickResetButton() {
        $('#accReset').click(function () {
            var u = $("#ClientCode").data("ClientCodeList");
            u.value("");       
        })
    }
```

Note : It does not work even with selectedIndex

Hope people can assist me with this issue as I tried multiple platform but without any luck.

Comment: Are you ok with reloading the whole page?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () { 
            //
            $("#reset").click(function ()
            {
                $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
            });
        });

    </script>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Javascript you can use the below.

```
<input type="button" id="accReset" value="Reset" onclick="Reset();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function Reset() {
    var dropDown = document.getElementById("DropdownName");
    dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code:

```
function onClickResetButton() {
    $('#accReset').click(function () {
        var u = $("#ClientCode").data("ClientCodeList");
        u.value(0);       
    })
}
```

Comment: @Daniel Instead of u.value("");  use u.value(0);